# VBA Code: How to reject a file import if the name isn't in sequential order?

Tags: vba, excel

I have yearly data files (text delimited) that will each be named "2016 latest", "2017 latest", "2018 latest", etc. I have a macro written that will bring up the file window and allow the user to chose the file and then automatically import it into the workbook. However, I want to include some error control that will reject the file and endsub if, for example, the last file uploaded was "2016 latest" and the file they try to upload is "2018 latest". I'm trying to prevent years from being duplicated or years from being skipped. How would I do this? I've attached the code I have so far.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportTextFile()

Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


Dim fName As String, LastRow As Long

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
        Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow))
            .Name = "sample"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = True
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

 Selection.EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

Comment: Dont put a picture of the code, copy/paste **inside** the question.

Comment: Okay thank you. It's fixed

Comment: If you don't want the user to have a choice, you shouldn't give the user a choice. Solve this problem by naming your files like 1601, 1602, 1603 or 201601, 201602, 201603 (each for Jan to Dec, 01 to 12). You can then easily write a very short routine which picks out the next file you want at that point, for example 1603 after 1602 was done. If a particular month is missing the procedure can decide whether to look for the next one after that or end the search (for example, if 1705 were the next one).

Comment: Are you loading all these files at once, or are they being loaded over a long time period?  (If they are yearly files, it seems possible that the intention is to load one file one year, and the next file twelve months later.)

Comment: They're being loaded over a long period of time. I unfortunately do not have a choice as to what the files are named. So the boundaries of the question stay as is.